# Google Oauth Verification not verify my App after a long time

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-fit

We have submit an Oauth App for verify Google Fit API. The Google does reply to us a few time. But after some email, they don't reply to us any more, and the App stuck in verification for a months already, we tried to resubmit the App, but still got not replies. Is there any way we can contact the Google Oauth team beside their email thread?
Another question, our app will try to get the user daily step count to sync to their profile. So which Scope we will need in Google Oauth, we only add https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read, but I'm not sure it will be enough.